# Como reduzir o script de INSERT no BD com PDO -> bindValue?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A alguma maneira de encurtar esse *script*?? Ou toda vez que eu for fazer um `INSERT` no bando de dados utilizando **PDO** e a função `bindValue`, vou ter que escrever linha por linha?? Ou da pra utilizar um array ou algo mais fácil e rápido.

```
//Prepara o cadastro
    $lc_reg = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO lc_users(u_username,u_email,u_pass,u_nome,u_sobrenome,u_dia,u_mes,u_ano)VALUES(:user,:email,:pass,:nome,:sobrenome,:dia,:mes,:ano,:sex)");
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":user",$reg_user);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":email",$reg_email);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":pass",$reg_senha);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":nome",$reg_nome);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":sobrenome",$reg_sobrenome);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":dia",$reg_dia);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":mes",$reg_mes);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":ano",$reg_ano);
    $lc_reg->bindValue(":sex",$reg_sex);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindValue()` ou  `bindParam()` passam apenas um valor para ser feito bind, a alternativa fica por conta do `execute()` que permite receber um array, sendo as chaves os nome dos indentificadores ou número no caso das interrogações.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela(campo1, campo2, campo3)VALUES(:valor1, :valor2, :valor3)");
$stmt->execute(array("valor1" => 1, "valor2" => 2, "valor3" => 3));
```

Ou

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela(campo1, campo2, campo3)VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array('a1', 'b2', 'c3'));
```